# Ways to convert String to char in java without built-in libs

Tags: java, string, char

is there a way to covert a string to an array of char without using any library functions (ex:- split,tocharArray etc)in java

Comment: why do you prefer doing stuff manually, when you have existing API to do so?

Comment: Define "library function".  There's no way to access the contents of a `String` without using its methods, which are all part of the Java library.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel?

Comment: yes there are ways to do this... but: WHY? homework? ;-)

Comment: In that case, run a loop over your String to manually read all the characters into a char[]. Use String.charAt(int) to get sinlge character from a String.

Comment: Without library functions? If you can't use charAt, you can do it with Reflection (ouch it would hurt to see such code)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "abcd";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray(); // What is the wrong with this way
```

You can manually construct a char array.

```
String str = "abcd";
char[] arr = new char[str.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: `charAt` is a library function, right?. It does this: `return value[index + offset];`

Comment: Y he said "_without using any library functions_"

Comment: In that case, you must not even use String.length() as it is library function. Do you expect to perform low-level operations to get char[]?

Comment: I'm just saying that if `String.length()` is ok, then `toCharArray()` should be as well :p

Answer (score 0):

A little method(),

```
public Character[] toCharacterArray(String s) {
   if (s == null) {
     return null;
   }
   Character[] array = new Characer[s.length()];
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      array[i] = new Character(s.charAt(i));
   }

   return array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Keyser. If s[i] worked, what would be need of converting it to another array :O. Since s would have been an array itself.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `java.io.StringReader`

Here is a small snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String s = "hello world";

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);

        char[] cc = new char[1];
        cc[0] = (char) reader.read();

        char[] tmpCC = null;

        int readChar = 0;
        int lenConcatenator = cc.length;
        while((readChar = reader.read())!=-1)
        {
            ++lenConcatenator;
            tmpCC = new char[cc.length];
            System.arraycopy(cc, 0, tmpCC, 0, cc.length);

            cc = new char[lenConcatenator];
            System.arraycopy(tmpCC, 0, cc, 0, tmpCC.length);

            cc[lenConcatenator - 1] = (char) readChar;
        }

        System.out.println(cc);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `toCharArray()` which is String library. This library can be replaced by its actual implementation in `java.lang.String` class.
Without this, if we can achieve please suggest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseStringWOInbuilt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] ch = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
        char temp;  
        for (int i = 0, j = ch.length-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            temp = ch[i];
            ch[i] = ch[j];
            ch[j] = temp;
        }
        System.out.println(new String(ch));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[] toMyArray(String s) {
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char[] output = new char[s.length()];
    try {
        while ((k = reader.read()) != -1) {
            output[i] = ((char) k);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this code only answer?

Comment: Yes, Java has a class StringReader for reading the character stream from string. Its read() method returns -1 if no character is read so I have used that to check if it is the end of string or not. I have stored the character one by one in a char array and after whole string characters are read, I have returned that array.